# Different behaviour between numpy array and plain list in Pipe library

Tags: python, numpy

I am testing the [Pipe](https://github.com/JulienPalard/Pipe) library for Python, which tries to simplify the processing of iterables, essentially allowing one to write

```py
ys = xs | f1 | f2 | f3
```

instead of

```py
ys = f3(f2(f1(xs))
```

The `Pipe` class itself is very short: just call the wrapped function when encountering a `__ror__` operation:

```py
import functools 

class Pipe:
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.function = function
        functools.update_wrapper(self, function)

    def __ror__(self, other):
        return self.function(other)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return Pipe(lambda x: self.function(x, *args, **kwargs))
```

However, I found a particular case where the output is not as expected:

```py
import numpy as np
from pipe import Pipe

y1 = np.array([1, 2, 3]) | Pipe(np.median)
y2 =          [1, 2, 3]  | Pipe(np.median)

print(y1)  # [1.0 2.0 3.0]
print(y2)  # 2.0
```

In both cases, I'd assume that `np.median` is applied on the iterable, but when the input is a numpy array, the function is **mapped** over the array, instead of making the array the actual argument (as is the case when using a plain list). That is, in the `__ror__` method, the `other` argument is an item from the array, as opposed to the actual array itself. I don't see how this can happen. Is it some numpy quirk?

Here's the [full reproducible example](https://www.online-python.com/HQ8y3NAxvV).

I didn't find any related issue in the project's repo.

Comment: `numpy.ndarray.__or__` takes priority over `Pipe.__ror__`.

Comment: Right. Is there a (syntactical) way to accommodate for this without breaking things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"I don't see how this can happen. Is it some numpy quirk?"*

NumPy has [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html). With the array `np.array([1, 2, 3])` on the left, the `__or__` method of the NumPy array treats the object `Pipe(np.median)` that it gets as its `other` argument as a scalar, and broadcasts it so that it acts like `[Pipe(np.median), Pipe(np.median), Pipe(np.median)]` (i.e. so the shape of `other` matches the shape of `self`).

Because `Pipe(np.median)` is not a type known to NumPy, the `other` argument is treated as an `object` array, and the `__or__` operation will attempt to operate elementwise on the inputs.  That means that eventually, the `__ror__` method of `Pipe(np.median)` is called, but it happens for each pair in `np.array([1, 2, 3])` and `[Pipe(np.median), Pipe(np.median), Pipe(np.median)]`.  That's why you get the result applied to each element, rather than `np.median` applied to the array on the left as a whole.  That is also why the data type of the result is `object` rather than a NumPy floating point type:

```
In [19]: np.array([1, 2, 3]) | Pipe(np.median)

Out[19]: array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0], dtype=object)
```

Regarding the handling of classes that implement `__or__`, the author of Pipe [says](https://github.com/JulienPalard/Pipe/issues/50#issuecomment-563950131) "That's the very limit of `Pipe`, there's no clean way to overcome this." See also [Pipe does not work if left side object defines `__or__`](https://github.com/JulienPalard/Pipe/issues/3).

---

For what its worth...

A modification of the code given in the question that would allow `Pipe` to work with a NumPy array (or any other object that implements `__or__`) is to provide an option to put a thin wrapper around data before it is sent into the pipe.  If the `__ror__` method of `Pipe` sees this wrapper, it unwraps the data, calls its function, and rewraps the result before returning it.  A final step at the end of the pipe is needed to unwrap data that was wrapped.  Perhaps something like this:

```
import functools 


class Wrap:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self._object = obj

    def unwrap(self):
        return self._object


class Pipe:
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.function = function
        functools.update_wrapper(self, function)

    def __ror__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Wrap):
            return Wrap(self.function(other.unwrap()))
        else:
            return self.function(other)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return Pipe(lambda x: self.function(x, *args, **kwargs))


class Unwrap:
    def __ror__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Wrap):
            return other.unwrap()
        else:
            return other
```

For example,

```
In [13]: a = np.array([1, 2, 3])

In [14]: Wrap(a) | Pipe(np.median) | Unwrap()
Out[14]: 2.0

In [15]: b = [1, 2, 3]

In [16]: Wrap(b) | Pipe(np.median) | Unwrap()
Out[16]: 2.0
```

---

One more follow-up...

If it is acceptable to require a wrapper at the input of the pipe and an unwrapper at the output, the pipe mechanism can be changed to allow arbitrary callables in the pipe without being wrapped in a `Pipe` class:

```
# A token to indicate the end of a pipe.
ExitPipe = None


class EnterPipe:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self._object = obj

    def __or__(self, other):
        if other == ExitPipe:
            return self._object
        if not callable(other):
            raise TypeError(f"pipe element '{other}' is not callable")
        return EnterPipe(other(self._object))
```

For example,

```
In [10]: a = np.array([1, 2, 3])

In [11]: EnterPipe(a) | np.sin | np.cos | max | ExitPipe
Out[11]: 0.9900590857598653

In [12]: max(np.cos(np.sin(a)))
Out[12]: 0.9900590857598653
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear exposition! I scanned the repo for issues concerning "numpy" specifically, hence missing your referred issue. All in all, this means that `Pipe` should be used for "plain" iterables (and generators), there's no point in further complicating things to support numpy arrays.

Comment: Defining `EnterPipe` and `ExitPipe` is a really clever and conceptually simple idea. Thank you!